# Deleteing a Node in a Binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

Iunderstand the basis of a deletion algorithm in a Binary Search tree and have created the following code to delete the largest value from the tree.

```
public void DelLargest()
{
    Node<T> del = this;
    boolean child = this.left.empty();
            boolean child2 = this.right.empty();
    right.DelLargest();
    if(child && child2)
        this.head = null;
    else if(child == true && child2 == false)
        this.head = left;


}
```

Basically what I have is that the recursion runs until 'this' is the rightmost node and then checks two cases, whether 'this' is a leaf, or whether 'this' has a left child. (The other case normally associated with this kind of algorithm is redundant because in finding the node with the largest value, I have gone as right as I can go.) The trouble I am having is getting the current node to then either point to null or to the value at Node left.

Note : This is what my instructor referred to as a "modern" Binary search Tree wherein a vertex or "filled" node and a nil or "empty" node are two subclasses of Interface Node which define the characteristics of each type.

I've managed to narrow the problem down to the fact that I do not have a method that returns a value of a given Node. Working on that now, input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the other answer you should use iterative approach.

In a BST the largest value is the rightmost node.
So do a scan and keep going right until you hit a null.
In the scan keep track of three nodes. (gpnode, pnode, node).
Once the scan is done you will have (gpnode,pnode,null)
Now there are 2 cases.

case 1:

`pnode` is a leaf. So change the edge `(gpnode,pnode)` to `(gpnode,null)`

case 2: (**EDITED**)

`pnode.lChild` is not null. Note that `pnode.rChild` will be null as the search would have terminated at that point.
Now change the edge `(gpnode,pnode)` to `(gpnode,pnode.lChild)`

Here is the pseudo code:

```
public class Node
{
    long key;
    Node lChild;
    Node rChild;
}

public void DelLargest()
{
    Node gpnode = null;
    Node pnode = null;
    Node node = root;
    while(node != null) // keep going right until a null is reached
    {
        gpnode = pnode;
        pnode = node;
        node = node.rChild;
    }
    if(pnode.lChild == null) // its a leaf node So change the edge (gpnode,pnode) to (gpnode,null)
    {
        if(gpnode.lChild == pnode)
        {
            gpnode.lChild = null;
        }
        else
        {
            gpnode.rChild = null;
        }
    }
    else // copy lChild's key to this node and delete lChild
    {
        if(gpnode.lChild == pnode)
        {
            gpnode.lChild = pnode.lChild;
        }
        else
        {
            gpnode.rChild = pnode.lChild;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Consider a tree where the right most node has a left child which is the root of another subtree. Copying pnode.lChild's value and deleting it means you lose all of those other nodes forever. You can't copy values and delete, you need to maintain the structure of the tree.

Comment: @BrendanMcKee: You are right. Fixed the description and pseudocode. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea. What you want to do is keep a reference to the right most nodes parent, and the right most nodes left child so then when you delete it you can attach the two.

Here's an iterative solution. This will generally be more efficient than recursion, but if you want recursion you should be able to adapt it:

```
public void delLargest() {
    // get rightmost node's parent
    Node<T> current = root;
    while(current.right != null && current.right.right != null) {
        current = current.right;
    }
    // get the rightmost nodes left node
    Node<T> left = current.right.left;
    // attach the parent and left
    current.right = left;
    // nothing points to the right most node anymore, so it will be garbage collected
}
```

Comment: You should be careful and should know what you are really doing here. `while(current.right != null && current.right.right != null)`. This looks ok and if the order is changed then it would end up with `NULLPointerException`. So better to use extra variables and leave the optimization to the compiler :)